# How can i restore the info.plist files of Safari?

Tags: safari, plist

I accidentally edited the info.plist file of Safari and now Safari does not start up giving the error "quit unexpectedly". How can i restore this file?

Comment: read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using this one I took from my copy of Safari, the latest version available on OS X 10.10...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Application-Group</key>
    <array>
        <string>dot-mac</string>
        <string>InternetAccounts</string>
    </array>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>14E39</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>css</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>css.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>text/css</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>CSS style sheet</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>pdf</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>pdf.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/pdf</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>PDF document</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>webarchive</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>webarchive.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/x-webarchive</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Web archive</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>ICExtension</key>
            <string>ARCHIVE</string>
            <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>webbookmark</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>webbookmark.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Safari bookmark</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>webhistory</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>webhistory.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Safari history item</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>webloc</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>webloc.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Web internet location</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>ilht</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>download</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>download10.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Safari download</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>safariextz</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>safariextz.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/x-safari-extension</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Safari extension</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>gif</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>gif.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>image/gif</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>GIF image</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>GIFf</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>html</string>
                <string>htm</string>
                <string>shtml</string>
                <string>jhtml</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>html.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>text/html</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>HTML document</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>HTML</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>ICExtension</key>
            <string>HTML</string>
            <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>js</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>js.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/x-javascript</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>JavaScript script</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>jpg</string>
                <string>jpeg</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>jpeg.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>image/jpeg</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>JPEG image</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>JPEG</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>ICExtension</key>
            <string>JPEG</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>jp2</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>jp2.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>image/jp2</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>JPEG 2000 image</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>jp2 </string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>txt</string>
                <string>text</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>txt.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>text/plain</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Plain text document</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>TEXT</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>ICExtension</key>
            <string>TXT</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>png</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>png.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>image/png</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>PNG image</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>PNGf</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>tiff</string>
                <string>tif</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>tiff.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>image/tiff</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>TIFF image</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>TIFF</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>ICExtension</key>
            <string>TIFF</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>url</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>url.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Web site location</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>LINK</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>ico</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>ico.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>image/x-icon</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Windows icon image</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>ICO </string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>xhtml</string>
                <string>xht</string>
                <string>xhtm</string>
                <string>xht</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>xhtml.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/xhtml+xml</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>XHTML document</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>ICExtension</key>
            <string>XHTML</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>xml</string>
                <string>xbl</string>
                <string>xsl</string>
                <string>xslt</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>xml.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>application/xml</string>
                <string>text/xml</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>XML document</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>ICExtension</key>
            <string>XML</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>svg</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>svg.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>image/svg+xml</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>SVG document</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>BrowserDocument</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Safari</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>8.0.7, Copyright © 2003-2015 Apple Inc.</string>
    <key>CFBundleHelpBookFolder</key>
    <string>Safari.help</string>
    <key>CFBundleHelpBookName</key>
    <string>com.apple.Safari.help</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>compass</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.Safari</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Safari</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>8.0.7</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>sfri</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>Web site URL</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>http</string>
                <string>https</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForScheme</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>Local file URL</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>file</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>10600.7.12</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>6D543f</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>14D2125</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.10internal</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0630</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>6D543f</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.productivity</string>
    <key>LSFileQuarantineEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.10.0</string>
    <key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
    <string>Yes</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Websites you visit may request your location.</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>BrowserApplication</string>
    <key>NSServices</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSKeyEquivalent</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>L</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Search With %WebSearchProvider@</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>searchWithWebSearchProvider</string>
            <key>NSPortName</key>
            <string>Safari</string>
            <key>NSSendTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.utf8-plain-text</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSMenuItem</key>
            <dict>
                <key>default</key>
                <string>Add to Reading List</string>
            </dict>
            <key>NSMessage</key>
            <string>addToReadingList</string>
            <key>NSPortName</key>
            <string>Safari</string>
            <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSTextContent</key>
                    <string>URL</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSLinkSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>http</string>
                        <string>https</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>NSSendTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.rtf</string>
                <string>public.utf8-plain-text</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSSupportsAutomaticTermination</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSSupportsSuddenTermination</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb</string>
    </array>
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Safari bookmark</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.safari.bookmark</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>webbookmark</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Safari extension</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.safari.extension</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>safariextz</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Safari history item</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.safari.history</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>webhistory</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```